# How to make the handle after animating in python turtle?

Tags: python, python-turtle

This is the bycicle i am trying  to make but i cant.

[image]

I am really sorry if it gets downgrades and i am really new to python turtle.
I am currently trying to animate. I am done with the animation but i am struglling with making the handle of the bycicle.
After writing the code it dosent make any change.
So if possible. Anyone can make the handle and  explain how he did it?
Thank you..

```
import time

def moving_wheel(turtle):
    turtle.fillcolor('orange')
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(20)
    turtle.end_fill()

def moving_handle(turtle):
    pos = turtle.pos()
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(70)
    turtle.left(120)
    turtle.forward(110)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(pos)
    turtle.right(210)
    
    turtle.pendown()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.setup(600, 600)
    screen.bgcolor('green')
    screen.tracer(0)

    t1 = turtle.Turtle()
    t2 = turtle.Turtle()
    t3 = turtle.Turtle()

    # set a turtle object color
    t1.color('red')
    t2.color('red')
    t3.color('red')

    # set turtle object speed
    t1.speed(0)
    t2.speed(0)
    t3.speed(0)

    t1.width(2)
    t2.width(2)
    t3.width(1.5)

    t1.hideturtle()
    t2.hideturtle()
    t3.hideturtle()

    # turtle object in air
    t1.penup()
    t2.penup()
    t3.penup()

    # set initial position
    t1.goto(-250, 0)
    t2.goto(-150,0)
    t3.goto(-150,20)
    t3.pendown()


    # move turtle object to surface
    t1.pendown()
    t2.pendown()

    # infinite loop
    while True:

        # clear turtle work
        t1.clear()
        t2.clear()
        t3.clear()

        # call function to draw ball
        moving_wheel(t1)
        moving_wheel(t2)
        moving_handle(t3)

        # update screen
        screen.update()

        # forward motion by turtle object
        t1.forward(0.1)
        t2.forward(0.1)
        t3.forward(0.1)
```

Comment: I don't understand problem. I see moving 2 wheels and moving "handle" (or maybe rather `"bicycle frame").

Comment: @furas I have uploaded the bycicle picture you can see there what i am trying to say. The bycicle is incomplete and i am not able to make it.

Comment: this needs only to use more `forward`, `left/right`, `penup/pendown`, etc. So you have to only sit and do it. There is no error in your code.

Comment: maybe you should draw triangles with angles 60 - and in all places use the same angle 60 (or 120). And if distance between centers of wheels in `dist` then triangles will have sides `dist/2`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your code. You have to only sit and add more `forward`, `left/right`, `penup/pendown`, etc. - and this need to test different value and see which gives expected result.

I would split problem into smaller figures with more regular angles and size.
Bottom part looks like 3 triangles and it would be simpler to use regular triangles with angles 60.

Maybe you should even create function `triangle(size)` for this.

This is what I tried to draw these triangles.

```
def moving_handle(turtle):
    pos = turtle.pos()
    
    # --- first triangle without last side ---
    
    # rotate to start position
    turtle.left(120)
    
    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(120)

    # move without drawing last side
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.left(120)
    turtle.pendown()

    # rotate back to old position
    turtle.left(-120)

    # --- second triangle
    
    # move to new position without drawing
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.left(180)
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.left(-180)
    turtle.pendown()
    
    # draw trangle
    
    # rotate to start position
    turtle.left(120)
    
    for _ in range(3):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(120)

    # rotate back to old position
    turtle.left(-120)

    # --- second triangle
    
    # draw trangle
    
    # rotate to start position
    turtle.left(60)
    
    for _ in range(3):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(120)

    # rotate back to old position
    turtle.left(-60)

    # move to the beginning
    
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(pos)
    turtle.pendown()
```

[image]